# Multipatch to polygon/polyline conversion in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro, cad, multipatch

I have a file captured from Bentley software already converted to .shp format. I would like to have polygon or polyline to be able to simply edit it but I don't know how to convert Multipatch to polyline/polygon without loosing Z-values. I tried `Multipatch Footprint` but as the result I have 2D layer. As well I tried to generate points using `Feature Vertices to Points` and it works, but my goal is to create TIN model and here I don't want to include all points (some of them are below desired surface).

Does ArcGIS Pro have another tool which could help me?

Comment: Do you have access to FME desktop?

Comment: Feel free to ask about other products in separate questions

Answer (score 1):

You said your goal is to create a TIN model so I assume you have access to Spatial Analyst. If so, you could try using the [Multipatch to Raster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/multipatch-to-raster.htm) tool of ArcGIS Pro.  The Z value will be stored as the raster cell value and you can either edit raster or convert it to shapefile for more convenient editing.

Comment: I have FME and I have shapefile made by conversion in this software. About the tool "Multipatch to Raster" I tried but unfortunately it does not allow me to do that, alert says: wrong file format. This is file with about 10 layers representing railway. I need to create surface based on that but it is not so simple as there are different lines on different levels and I need firstly to delete some of them.

Comment: @AngelaG Maybe update the post with the error message you got. Does ArcGIS even allow you to run the tool? Or did you see a red cross next to your input bar and were unable to proceed from there?

Answer (score 0):

So finally I could convert multipatch file to raster using "`Multipatch to Raster`" tool in ArcGIS Pro. I received 7 different raster files made of 7 layers and then I used "`Raster Calculator`" to sum them all together and to have one final result.