# ArcGIS Pro: Convert Multipatch Shapes to 3D-Polylines

Tags: arcgis-pro, convert, polyline-creation, multipatch

Multipatch shapes which represent tubes should be converted to a 3D-polyline which will represent the the trajectory of the tubes (i.e. the center of the rings which build the tube). The tubes are shown in the figures [**A**] with individual colors and in [**B**] all in gray. My attempt was similar as in the case [Multipatch to polygon/polyline conversion in ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306076/multipatch-to-polygon-polyline-conversion-in-arcgis-pro) to (1) create polygons from multipatch by `Multipatch Footprint` and then (2) to create 3D-polylines from polygons by `Polygon To Line`. However, the resulting polylines are cumbersome to handle: they are split by each intersection of any of the polygons generating many small pieces of polylines. By this, I assume that my approach is not an advisable one.

Is there any recommendable proceeding to convert multipatch shapes to 3D-polylines which represent the trajectory of the multipatch shapes?

Software used: ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0 on Windows 11 Pro

[image]